# Actionlib SimpleActionClient

Tags: actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I was using SimpleActionClient follow this tutorial: ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals

It was able to run it. I try to run multiple goals, but the program stop once there is a goal achieve **SUCCEEDED** state.

**My question here was:**

1. is there anyway to terminate **MoveBaseClient ac("move_base", true);** after achieve the goal and recall another new **SimpleActionClient**?
2. is there anyway to reset the state into the earliest state of actionlib such as **PENDING**? So that I can send another goal using the same executable file.
3. How do I use *void actionlib::SimpleActionClient< ActionSpec >::setSimpleState(const SimpleGoalState & next_state)* ? What value I should put into this function? I test is not a string or char.

Thanks for answering.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53475/actionlib-simpleactionclient/) by [Pin Kid](https://answers.ros.org/users/4062/pin-kid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It would be helpful if you describe the way you submit multiple goals to the action server. What do you mean by the program stops once the goal status becomes `SUCCEEDED`?

According to the `SimpleActionClient` documentation on `sendGoal()` -

> If a previous goal is already active
> when this is called. We simply forget
> about that goal and start tracking the
> new goal. No cancel requests are made.

I have been using SimpleActionClient to send a sequence of goals one after the other without any issue. All I did was to check for the status of the current goal and once it is done, send another goal

```
if(ac.getState() == actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState::SUCCEEDED)
    // Then, send the next goal
```

---

Originally posted by [Namal Senarathne](https://answers.ros.org/users/3870/namal-senarathne/) with karma: 246 on 2013-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-06-10**:
Hi

I am using actionlib to move the bsae of the robot to certain coordinates.

I give the coordinates as follows:

move_base_msgs::MoveBaseGoal goal;

goal.target_pose.pose.position.x = 2;

goal.target_pose.pose.position.y = 6;

double th=D2R*(atan2( msg.pose.pose.orientation.y, msg.pose

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-06-10**:
geometry_msgs::Quaternion gth = tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw(th);

goal.target_pose.pose.orientation =gth;

Then the robot moves to the desired coordinates, however the robot has a rotation behaviour when it reaches the goal.

How can avoid that rotation? I just want the robot to arrive to the des